# Update SQL query to change a field based on ID in same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I have a table in a Database called Menu. Here are the fields from this table:

```
`ID`,
`CompanyID`, 
`MenuName`, 
`MenuLink`, 
`ImageLink`, 
`ListOrder`, 
`Popup`, 
`Target`, 
`ParentMenuID`, 
`IsActive`,
`IsAdmin`
```

As you can see from the first image the MenuName contains the list of all the different menus.

[image]

This is a bit complicated so I hope I am explaining this right. See the row where CompanyID is equal to 99. In the second image the ID is equal to 1807.

[image]

Now in the third image see how ParentMenuID is set to 1807 when the CompanyID is also equal to 99. So when MenuName = Public Holidays, I need to set the field ParentMenuID. I get this value from ID when MenuName = Lookups.
So my problem is how to I set all the ParentMenuID fields when MenuName = Public Holiday to match the ID field when MenuName = Lookups.

[image]

You can see if the third image the other ParentMenuID fields are equal to 1. I have nearly 100 rows in this table and can't update them all one at a time. Is there an SQL query that can help here?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question. There are too many variable in the question for my brain to process :)

I understood the structure of your db but didnt understood what is the query you are looking for

Comment: Is it 

IF MenuName=Public Holiday and Menuname != Lookup then THEN
     Change all the ParentMenuID=1
End

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat ok I tried editing my question. I know its complicated but if you look at the images you can see what I trying to do. The ID when MenuName = Lookups needs to be the same as ParentMenuID when MenuName = Public Holidays

Comment: Ok see if i get it right:

Set ParentMenuID  when MenuName="Public Holiday" with the value of ID when Menuname=Lookups

You want to point a Parent Menu when the User select a Public Holiday. Is this functionality you want to achieve here?

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat yes that's right

Comment: I see @Stephan B has given you the answer. Try it out and tell if that worked.

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat no that solution didn't work. It says 0 rows were affected

Comment: Can you sent the sql of this table to abhilash.c@spurtreetech.com?

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat thanks I emailed you now

Comment: There is no schema in that sql :)

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat I just exported the SQL table. It is not the whole database

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat the solution given by Stephan B works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to update all rows where MenuName is "Public Holidays" and set the ParentMenuID to the ID of the row where MenuName is "Lookups" and the same CompanyID? Try this query:

```
UPDATE Menu p
INNER JOIN Menu l ON (l.CompanyID = p.CompanyID)
SET p.ParentMenuID = l.ID
WHERE p.MenuName = 'Public Holidays' -- Fixed Spelling 
AND l.MenuName = 'Lookups'
```

As I am a bit guessing here, I Suggest you make a backup of your data first or test this on a small subset first to see if it really works the way you want it to.

[Syntax borrowed from this question on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41261/update-table-based-on-the-same-table)

Comment: To test I just added the line p.CompanyID = 103 so it will only affect one row but it didn't work

Comment: Any errors? I currently have no mysql at hand, you could create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some test rows to let us check.

Comment: No I when I ran it in MySQL Workbench it just gave the message 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: This solution did work. There was a spelling mistake for Public but fixing that it worked. Thanks